# Why is addLast() in Java replacing my linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a class that is supposed to create a hash table with a linked list for the values. If the key is new, it creates a linked list, and if it already exists it is supposed to append it to the end of the list. For some reason, when I use addLast() it is replacing the contents of my list. Can you see what I am doing wrong? Here is my code. Thank you!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Semantic {
    String currentScope;
    Stack theStack = new Stack();
    HashMap<String, LinkedList> SymbolTable= new HashMap<String, LinkedList>();


    public boolean insertSymbol(String key, SymbolTableItem value){
        LinkedList<SymbolTableItem> temp = new LinkedList<SymbolTableItem>();
        SymbolTableItem obj;
        if(!isContained(SymbolTable.get(key), value)){
            if(SymbolTable.get(key) != null){
                temp = SymbolTable.get(key);
            }
            temp.addLast(value);
            SymbolTable.put(key, temp);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isContained(LinkedList list, SymbolTableItem obj){
        if(list == null) return false;
        while(!list.isEmpty()){
            SymbolTableItem item;
            item = (SymbolTableItem) list.removeFirst();
            if(item.equals(obj))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String printValues(){
        return SymbolTable.toString();
    }

    public boolean isBoolean(){
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isTypeMatching(){
        return true;
    }

    public void stackPush(String theString){
        theStack.add(theString);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should parametrize your `LinkedList`s appropriately, it might make your life easier.

Comment: You mean, differently that including the Linked class in the declaration? Could you give me an example?

Comment: you have a lot of issues... use `contains` instead of `get(key)` cause HashTable don't accept null , and you don't have to added again when you modify the linkedList

Comment: @bstrong As in, `LinkedList<SymbolTableItem>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `isContained` removes every element up to and including the search element `SymbolTableItem` `obj`.

If `obj` occurs last in the `LinkedList` then everything will be removed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize they were staying connected.

Comment: reimeus by the way you could tell that he has a lot of issues in his code rather than this.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check around item = (SymbolTableItem) list.removeFirst();
The isContained method looks messed up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating a new linked list before you test whether the value is new or not.  Try not creating the linked list until after you've tried to retrieve that value.

Comment: i don't think if that is the issue he has.. did you test it? the problem is `item = (SymbolTableItem) list.removeFirst();`